# BackgroundWorker - Form Refresh

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, invoke

I'm trying to make it so that my form refreshes when I click a button. However I keep getting an error

> 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on.'

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        worker.DoWork += formReload;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    static BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    private void formReload(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs ev)
    {
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I've tried to research it, and I get that I have to use the Invoke method, however I don't understand where to put it, and why to use it? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Jarrod

Comment: post some code of DoWork, you have to put it into that method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: move Refresh from `bg_DoWork` to `bg_runworkercompleted`

Comment: You could have Googled the error message first...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply. I have nothing in DoWork, so I posted the this.Refresh(); in there, however now there's no error, but it doesn't work either. What I have in my code is a variable, and in the form_load there's a switch case, so if the variable = 1, then do the code that's in case 1.

Comment: I did try to google the error, hence why I know about the invoke method, however I didn't understand it, nor where to put it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your code does nothing, the `DoWork` is unnecessary. You can rewrite your code as:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

static BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(new Action(()=>Refresh()));
}
```

Assuming that you subscribed the `DoWork` method in the contructor using

```
worker.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
```

Take note that a `Refresh` doesn't change anything. What do you have to refresh?

Comment: Hi, thanks! The error doesn't appear anymore, but the form doesn't seem to be reloading

Comment: I've edited the reply, what do you have to reload? Where is the code to reload the form?

Comment: What I thought it'd do was refresh everything (even in form_load). Because I have a int called refresh, so everytime the form is refreshed is adds one. Then my idea was to run a switch which gets the refresh int and draw different things in each case? If that makes sense

Comment: the Form_Load is called only once (when the form is actually loaded the first time). If you want to call it you don't have to use the `Refresh` but call it explicitly: use `this.Invoke(new Action(()=>form_Load(null,null)));`

Comment: Thankyou very much :) Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No Problem, I see you are new here: if the answer fits your need please mark it as accepted (put the green tick under the answer's score), thank you